# Looking into new .NET8 Blazor Web App. How to add a .js to a .razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

It should be very simple, but I really can't find a way to add a .js to project.
I have created a .razor page with a simple code like this:

```
@page "/text"
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime 
@implements IAsyncDisposable 


<h2>Test  @text</h2>
<button @onclick="LoadText">Load</button>

@code
{
    string text = "";
    private IJSObjectReference module;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            module = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
                "import", "./js/index.js");
        }
    }
    private async Task LoadText()
    {
        text = await module.InvokeAsync<string>("logToConsole");
    }
}
```

and a .js file with function I put in created in the wwwroot directory named js:

```
export function logToConsole() {
    return "My text"
}
```

Instead of appending text, It throws an error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Failed to resolve module specifier '.js/index.js'
      TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '.js/index.js'
          ...
```

Tried to change path, tried all kind of rendering modes, but it didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. How are your component and js file located in project? Usually static files (incl JS) are served from under wwwroot, which means relative script location  may be different during runtime vs design-time. I would try getting it to work using exact JS paths, a la  `/js/index.js`.

Comment: I failed to replicate your issue with your code in my side. Please make sure the js file is in wwwroot/js/index.js, then before loading /text, please clean the cache in your browser and then test again... Or you might create a new Blazor web app with `auto` render mode, and test again. All worked for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV37I.png  clear site data and then hard reload

Comment: @TinyWang thank you, indeed, looks like I didn't clear cash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you are using `InteractiveAuto` so I deduce you were using a blazor web app and choosing the auto template, or we should get below error.

[image]

I had a test in my side but didn't reproduce your issue with your code.And I think `./js/index.js` should also be correct if it's placed in `wwwroot` folder. Because [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#load-a-script-from-an-external-javascript-file-js-collocated-with-a-component) mentioned

> When the app is published, the framework automatically moves the
> script to the web root. Scripts are moved to bin/Release/{TARGET
> FRAMEWORK MONIKER}/publish/wwwroot/{PATH}/Pages/{COMPONENT}.razor.js

So I assume that the issue might result from the browser cache and suggest clearing cache then test. Thanks for OP's confirmation that this do worked.

[image]